# PHP session var disappears when iframe reloads

Tags: php, session-variables

I'm very new to PHP... and have a REST api which sets a session var when a user signs in:

```
$a = session_id();
if(empty($a)) session_start();
$_SESSION['id']=...
```

When I call a testFunction in the same browser (anoter tab) the session var is still the same:

```
$sessionID = session_id();
if(empty($sessionID)) session_start();
echo($_SESSION['id']);
```

When I Later open an iframe on the page it's still fine.

BUT, when the page inside the iframe reloads to another url, the session is lost...

```
$_SESSION['id'] // gives error: Undefined index: id
```

That is, I'm always staying on the same page but my iframe is changing urls.

Am I missunderstanding php session vars? Am I missusing it? Both?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `session_start()` on the iframe code too, are you actually calling it ?

Answer (score 0):

You *need* to call [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) whenever you are using session. You don't need to check `session_id()`.

> `session_start()` creates a session **or resumes the current one** based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

Comment: When I add sesssion_start() to some of the api's functions it gives me a crashes with a "Slim Application Error....A session had already been started - ignoring session_start".

Comment: @Cotten Oh well I understand what you're doing... you starts the session *inside* some API functions, but I think a majority of us would just place it at the start of the scripts.